# Need to create a flag based off of a date column and today's date

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with random dates in column A.  I want to create a flag (`Y`) for anything that is >= 3 days from today's date.  To get a little more complicated, I would like to add another level to this formula. I was thinking an IF(AND statement but can't figure out how to structure it, that says: if the date in A2 is >= 3 days from today's date and B2 = "Y" then `Y`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(AND(ABS(TODAY()-A2)>=3,B2="Y"),"Y","")
```

copied down to suit.

However your question is not clear at least about (i) what is where and (ii) whether `>= 3 days` is both forwards and backwards, or not. Also, for one of the triggers and one of the results to be the same may be confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question.  I have a random date in Column A.  I have a Y or N flag in column B.  I want to create another flag for anything >= 3 days from todays date and where column B = "Y".  Hoepfully that makes more sense.

Comment: This formula worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help!